# How to check two dots placed together and quotation marks in email?

Tags: python, regex, string, email

I've got a task to solve:

> Write a function on python, which checks an e-mail on compliance with these
> rules:
>
> 1. e-mail consists of the name and domain parts, and the "@" mark is between them;
> 2. the domain part is between 3 and 256 symbols, is a set of non-empty strings, consisting of a-z 0-9_- symbols separated by dot;
> 3. each component of the domain part can't begin or end with "-" symbol;
> 4. the name part (before @) is no more than 128 symbols, consists of a-z0-9"._-;
> 5. in the name part, we can't write two dots going together "..";
> 6. if we have double quotes in the name part (") , they should have a pair ("blabla");
> 7. we also can write "!,:" symbols in the name part, but only between double quotes.

I wrote a small regular expression step-by-step up to 4th point:

```
((?!-)[A-Z0-9"\.\-_]{1,128}(?<!-)@(?!-)[A-Z0-9\-_.]{3,256}(?<!-))
```

but I stuck on 5th and 6th.

How to implement these conditions in my regexp? I tried to add the

```
|(?:\.(?!\.))
```

in the end, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have a suggestion for your third point. Instead of checking presence of `-`, just don't include it. Will save you and the machine work of `look around`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to do this in regexp, [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is an example of an email validator written in regex with Perl, to this day that monstrosity haunts my dreams.

Use a proper parser, you should try looking at the source of the [validate_email](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/blob/master/validate_email.py) library and make change to serve your purposes. [This](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator) might also be a good source to use as base.

Comment: I guess OP is doing some sort of homework. Because I never saw anyone including `special symbols` in name part of email.

P.S: **Haunting dreams are inevitable when it comes to e-mail regex.**

Comment: @noob Perhaps, but it's good practice anyway to learn when to use a parser and when to use regex.

Comment: [Put down the chocolate-covered banana and step away from the European currency systems.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)

Comment: I second parser precedence over regex in hours of crisis.